# Symmetric Product of a Manifold is a Manifold?

Tags: general-topology

Define $S_n(M) = M^n/S_n$ to be the nth symmetric product of a manifold $M$,
where $(m_1,\ldots,m_n) \sim (m'_1,\ldots,m'_n)$ if $\sigma(m_1,\ldots,m_n) = (m'_1,\ldots,m'_n)$ for some $\sigma \in S_n$,
equipped with the obvious topology.

1. Is it true that every such $S_n(M)$ is a manifold? 
   If not,

   1. What is a counterexample?
   2. For what $M$ is $S_n(M)$ guaranteed to be a manifold and why?

Comment: topological?  smooth?  analytic?  with-boundary?

Comment: Without boundary this already fails for $S_2(\mathbb{R})$ which is a half-plane. The diagonal is problematic. But I suspect that $S_n(M)$ is a (topological) manifold with boundary.

Comment: @freakish I suspect even worse.  It is certainly an orbifold and hence stratified, but I don't see why it can't have lower-dimensional singular strata in the boundary.

Comment: The symmetric power of at least 2 points in a $d$-manifold is a manifold with boundary for $d=1$, a manifold for $d=2$, and a non-manifold for $d \geq 3$.  See my MO answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/456870/317